# Setting the Dates properly in Orange Times series module

Tags: orange

I am successfully using an Orange Time Series model to make ARIMA model predictions.

I am struggling to get the forecasts to show at the end of series in a line chart. A 4 period forecast shows a series of 1-4 instead of the future dates.

I've set the column type as Datetime in the CSV load.  The Time series loads properly in the line chart but the forecast doesn't.

[image]
[image]

Any help getting the date series to work properly would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Set it as a Meta. All the used data can be features, but make a target as well, what you would like to predict.
In the model, set the "forecast steps ahead" with the number, what you would like to predict in further dates ahead.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).